# Python 3.4 and the module "tweepy"

Tags: python, tweepy

I was just playing around with "tweepy" but it does not seem to work for me with Python 3.4. The example code from github (see below) works fine on Windows 7 and Python 2.7.9 but for some reason I just get an authorization error when I use the same code on my Linux machine with Python 3.4. Did anybody else have the same issues?! If so is there a solution?

EDIT

Well... I'm an idiot. The problem was actually related to my system clock and incorrect set hardware clock or something. I readjusted everything and that was actually the root of the problem. So the code works fine.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Go to http://apps.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret will be generated for you after
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

# After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
# Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    """
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['basketball'])
```

Comment: The code you posted works *just fine* on Python 3.4. I am not getting any authorization errors using my own tokens. Tripple-check your tokens.

Comment: Tweepy got supported on python 3.X  some month ago so i dont think there is a problem if you are using your own tokens and keys as Martijn Pieters just said.

Comment: Well... thanks so far. Although I'm using the same .py file I use on Windows and I can't get it to work here under Linux with Python 3... no idea I think I will try Python 2.7 here. Thanks though